# Matching 2 SQL tables with specific criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi let say I have 2 tables-

Table-1

```
+-------+-------+-------+
| Col-1 | Col-2 | Col-3 |
+-------+-------+-------+
| X1    | a     | XX1   |
+-------+-------+-------+
| X2    | b     | XX2   |
+-------+-------+-------+
| X3    | c     | XX3   |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

And Table-2

```
+--------+--------+
| Col-21 | Col-22 |
+--------+--------+
| a      | YY1    |
+--------+--------+
| c      | YY2    |
+--------+--------+
```

Now I want to merge these 2 tables with below scheme

1. Match `Col-2` of 1st table and `Col-21` with 2nd table
2. If match found then create a new column with the value of `Col-22`
3. If no match found then value of `Col-2` will be placed in that new column

So my resulting table will be

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| Col-1 | Col-2 | Col-3 | Col-4 |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| X1    | a     | XX1   | YY1   |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| X2    | b     | XX2   | b     |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| X3    | c     | XX3   | YY2   |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

And I want to fetch this entire new table with `SELECT` command.

Any pointer what will be the `SQL query` to achieve this?

Comment: Pointers, use a LEFT JOIN between the two tables and use CASE WHEN in your SELECT part to include col-22 or col-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are describing `left join` with `coalesce()`:

```
select t1.*, coalesce(t2.col22, t1.col2) as col4
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.col2 = t2.col21;
```